# Can we turn our Android device into a beacon?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

Hi recently I started working on beacons. I am using estimote beacons for my purpose. But I got a doubt whether we can turn our device into beacons. If not why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is now possible in Android 5.0 and to a limited extent in Android 4.4.3+.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25035954/1461050

Unfortunately, this is not possible as of the latest Android 4.4.2, because Android does not support BLE peripheral mode needed to advertise as an iBeacon.  See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/12/15/why-android-devices-cant-act-as-ibeacons.html) for details.

The good news is that peripheral mode support has been added to the Android open source project, so this may be possible in a future release, perhaps Android 5.0.  While Google has made no announcements, look for a release in June 2014 during the Google I/O conference.