# indoor positioning system using bluetooth without additional devices (e.g. ibeacon)

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I want to develop an app using the Indoor Positioning system to track the location of users of my app. i researched internet but couldn't find any way of developing it without the use of any additional devices other than mobile device like `ibeacon`. i found following git repo and docs which make use of `ibeacon`.

https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK

Excerpt from the above link

> We know that building the next generation of context-aware mobile apps
>   requires more than just iBeacon™ hardware. That's why we've built
>   smarter software that abstracts away the difficulty of understanding
>   proximity and position within a given space.

I want to make use of mobile device's bluetooth. Suggest me the links or ways to achieve the IPS using bluetooth.

Answer (score 5):

[IndoorAtlas](http://www.indooratlas.com/) has a software-only indoor positioning solution for iPhone and Android devices. SDK and mapping tools are available for free on the developer section.

Comment: i am looking into it, exploring it for free version. did you use it.

Comment: can we use or customize this to show some real time position information in realtime while using free version.

Answer (score 1):

*For an `Android` Device:*

If you have an `Android` device with `L (5.0)` support (also i think that some features are also available in `v:4.4.3+` ), you can convert it to act as a `Beacon`.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033940/can-a-htc-advertise-itself-as-a-ble-beacon/25035954#25035954) link for getting an idea on how it works